# How to fix stage for use with SonarQube in JenkinsPipeline

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I am setting up my pipeline to do a SonarQube scan on a dotnet project. This is the stage:

```
stage('SonarQube analysis') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('My Sonar') {
        dotnet "/usr/local/sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" begin /k:${SONARQUBEPROJECTKEY}
        dotnet build "src/hub-backend.sln"
        dotnet "/usr/local/sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" end 
    }
}
```

However, this fails and returns this error:

```
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://<removed>/scm/<removed>/jenkins-stuff.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 30: expecting '}', found 'begin' @ line 30, column 84.
   ild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll" begin /k:$
```

This errors says that it is expecting '}' but I don't see where that would be. The nesting of curly braces seem to be correct.

Can somebody help me understand this error?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a `sh` or `bat` in front of the `dotnet` (or is `dotnet` a jenkins pipeline step implemented by some jenkins plugin?).

Assuming that your `dotnet` is a command that's installed for you jenkins user on your linux slaves.

```
stage('SonarQube analysis') {
    withSonarQubeEnv('My Sonar') {
        sh "dotnet \"/usr/local/sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll\" begin /k:${SONARQUBEPROJECTKEY}"
        sh "dotnet build \"src/hub-backend.sln\""
        sh "dotnet \"/usr/local/sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll\" end"
    }
}
```